# Jasmine service error : Unknown provider: domSvcProvider <- domSvc

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

My actual controller has a few more services, I made a strip down version in an attempt to track down this service injection issue.

Any ideas?

```
var testApp = angular.module("testApp",[]);
  testApp.controller('testCtrl',['$scope','domSvc',testCtrl]);

  function testCtrl($scope,domSvc){

      $scope.testone = function(){
        return "testone";
      };
  }


----------

describe('Main tests', function() {

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('testApp'));

    var $controller, 
        $injector,
        domSvc;


    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$controller_,_$injector_){
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $injector = _$injector_;
    }));

    it('testone should return the string testone',function(){
        var $scope = {};
        var domSvc = $injector.get('domSvc');
        var controller = $controller('testCtrl',{$scope : $scope, domSvc : domSvc});
        expect($scope.testone()).toEqual('testone');
    });
});
```

Comment: Where you do you register the service called `domSvc`?

Comment: @SunilD. Yep, I forgot to include  a module that had my registered services. Silly mistake .

Comment: @SunilD. Feel free to post this as an answer and I will accept it. Gracias .